# ORACLE APEX How to upload a JSON file from client side?

Tags: json, database, oracle-apex

I'm using APEX 5.1 I have an existing table with a CLOB column. 
The user should be able to select the file from the client directory and upload the file(JSON) into this CLOB column of this table from the UI. If the row already exists (depending on id column in the same table), the CLOB column should be updated with the updated file, otherwise a new row is inserted with new id column and uploaded file. any ideas are appreciated ,thanks for your help.

I found a similar plugin, but there it’s necessary to copy the contents into the field. [apex-plugin-clob-load](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-plugin-clob-load)
This is not what I wanted (

JSON file is large [NVD NIST JSON file](https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2018.json.zip)

Maybe there is an opportunity to do it through 'file browser' or do I need to code a parsing procedure for this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!
[apex-plugin-dropzone](https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone)